# SQL: Foreign key that is a child of another foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I'd like to ask regarding a particular issue I have.

For example, I have a `Student` table that has a `SchoolID` and a `ClassID`, both of which are foreign keys to the `School` and `Classroom` tables respectively. The `Class` table has a `SchoolID` column which is a foreign key to the `School` table.

Is there any way I can ensure that the `ClassID` in the `Student` table is a child of the `SchoolID`, or must I remove the `SchoolID` and just live with the `ClassID` in order to prevent any possible discrepancies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, technically you should remove the `Student.SchoolId` foreign key, if Class already has `SchoolId`, as this already defines the relationship between `Student` and `School`.

That said, there are some common 'exceptions' to this, e.g.:

1. If the relationship between `Student` and `School` can mean something different than the relationship between `Class` and `School` (e.g. if the student goes to School X as 'his/her main school', but then also attends an extra mural Class Y at School Z). (Actually, this could highlight a modelling error, i.e. Student : Class might actually be a many to many relationship)
2. For performance reasons it is sometimes (a somewhat reluctant) choice to add the parent's foreign key to a child to avoid the need to join back to parent. But as you say, this can result in integrity issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can enforce it by having multiple columns in your foreign key reference to the `Classes` table:

```
create table Schools (
    SchoolID int not null primary key,
    Name varchar(30) not null unique
)
go
create table Classes (
    ClassID int not null primary key,
    SchoolID int not null foreign key references Schools (SchoolID),
    Name varchar(30) not null,
    constraint UQ_Class_Schools UNIQUE (ClassID,SchoolID),
    constraint UQ_Class_Names UNIQUE (SchoolID,Name)
)
go
create table Students (
    StudentID int not null primary key,
    SchoolID int not null foreign key references Schools (SchoolID),
    ClassID int not null,
    Name varchar(95) not null,
    constraint FK_Student_Classes FOREIGN KEY (ClassID,SchoolID) references Classes (ClassID,SchoolID)
)
```

Depending on taste, you may decide to also declare a foreign key *just* on the `ClassID` column in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

The Student table should reference Class.

```
create table Student (
  ...
  SchoolID integer not null,
  ClassID integer not null,
  foreign key (SchoolID, ClassID) references Class (SchoolID, ClassID),
  ...
);
```

In turn, the Class table should reference School.