# Is there something like a "Super-Foreign-Key" for this situation?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have several tables (all columns are integer for the sake of discussion):

TableX:

- IdItem (PK)
- Level (PK)
- OtherFields (PK)
- SomeOtherFields

TableItems:

- IdItem (PK)
- IdCategory

TableCategoryLevels:

- IdCategory (PK)
- Level     (PK)

I have only one TableItems and one TableCategoryLevels but I have several TableXs, they just differ for the "Other Fields" and "SomeOtherFields".

I need a FK that prevents INSERT into the TableXs if it is not possible to associate an Item with a certain Level, taking into account the relation existing between Items and Category and between Category and Level.

Is there a special FK that allows this?

In my case, I have already got a different solution where I keep a FK from TableX to a fourth table always filled (through a merge) with the INNER JOIN of TableItems and TableCategoryLevels.

But I am interested in knowing if a more exotic solution exists.

Thankx

Comment: I am sure this makes sense to you because you are close to the project. But for the rest of this just doesn't make any sense. Maybe if you create some sample tables and explain what you are trying to do more clearly we can help.

Comment: You can do this with a check constraint that calls a UDF, but I'm inclined to think there's probably a better way to design your tables.

Comment: I am sorry there's not much more to explain. Let's try an example
 Say I have an Item Cat, its Category is Mammal, and I have an Item Eagle, its category is Bird.
 In the third Table I specify that Mammals can only have Level 1 or 2, while Birds can only have Level 2 or 3.
 I need a way to prevent inserting Lion ( a Mammal) in the TableX with level 3.
 Let's say I inherited this DB and I can't change now the way things are, I hope you can understand this. Isn't this the best DB architecture ever? Yes. 
 I know this, but i need to stuck with these tables and a solution in these circumstances

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreign Key dependency on another Foreign Key as it's parent key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381129/foreign-key-dependency-on-another-foreign-key-as-its-parent-key)

Comment: NO, this is denormalized structure.

Comment: You can use a trigger to prevent insert like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255730/create-trigger-prevent-insert